# Access module declared on the parent level in Terraform

Tags: terraform

I plan to use multiple AWS Accounts for setting my network and infrastructure via Terraform. I have a network account on my AWS organization where I plan to put my VPCs, Subnets and Security Groups then I have a sandbox account where I plan to put my EC2 instances and RDS.

Folder structure is something like below with an intended modular approach.

```
|-- terraform
|   |--- network
|         |---- modules
|               |--- vpc
|                     |--- main.tf
|                     |--- variables.tf 
|   |--- network
|         |---- modules
|               |--- sg
|                     |--- main.tf
|                     |--- variables.tf 
|-- main.tf
```

The root **main.tf** content is something like

```
variable "region" {
    type = string
    default = "us-west-2"
}

provider "aws" {
    alias = "network"
    region = var.region
}

module "network" {
    source = "./network"
    providers = {
        aws = aws.network
    }
}

provider "aws" {
    alias = "sandbox"
    region = var.region
}

module "sandbox" {
    source = "./sandbox"
    providers = {
        aws = aws.sandbox
    }
}
```

Below is the content of **sandbox/main.tf** where I intended to access an output from network module inside the sandbox module.

```
module "sg" {
    source = "./modules/sg"
    nw_stack_vpc_id = module.network.vpc.nw_stack_vpc_id
}
```

Emphasis on the `module.network.vpc.nw_stack_vpc_id`.
When I try to do `terraform apply`. There error will be: `no module call named network is declared in module.sandbox`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't reference a module that way. You will have to pass in the VPC ID to the `sandbox` module, and then have the `sandbox` module pass it to the `sg` module.

```
module "sandbox" {
    source = "./sandbox"
    providers = {
        aws = aws.sandbox
    }

    # Note: You will have to add a nw_stack_vpc_id input variable in the sandbox module
    nw_stack_vpc_id = module.network.vpc.nw_stack_vpc_id
}
```

Then inside the `sandbox` module:

```
module "sg" {
    source = "./modules/sg"
    nw_stack_vpc_id = var.nw_stack_vpc_id 
}
```